# How to get data from a different database and save it to another database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I don't know if this problem of mine is possible. Is it? I have a library system. I add and edit new books in the Catalog Database. In other words, the Catalog Database is for adding/editing books only. I have another Database (not table) for Borrowing Books. I want to store these books, which are viewed through Catalog DB, to Borrowing DB.

I have a snippet for getting data from Catalog DB

```
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("catalog", $con);

$acc_number=$_GET["acc_number"];

$query="select * from branch where acc_number = '$acc_number'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  //echo $row[1];
}
<textarea name="title" disabled><?php echo $row[1];?></textarea>
```

And a button for the submission (store to borrowing database). If button is clicked, it's where my problem occurs. I just got a blank page after submitting it. Here is my process.php:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("catalog", $con);

$acc_number = $_POST['acc_number'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from books where acc_number='$acc_number'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("borrowing", $con);

  $query="INSERT INTO borrowers (title) VALUES ('$title')";
  mysql_query($query);
  if($query){
    header("Location:../librarysystem/books.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can both databases be accessed through the same connection string or do you have two separate connections that need to be made?

Comment: I have two separate connections that need to be made.

Comment: Why do you have to make two separate connections? If they're on the same MySQL server, you should be able to use them both on the same connection.

Comment: I don't understand your second script. What is the purpose of the `SELECT` query? You're not using anything it returns, you just keep inserting the same title into the `borrowers` table in a loop.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible. This could apply to anyone who wanted to have data processed through this (database to a database). And that is my another option: shifting it to one connection.

Comment: You don't need to call `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` each time through the loop.

Comment: Getting everything what the account number holds.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you can't do joins between them. You have to transfer all the data via PHP variables.

Comment: @Cecil I understand what the SELECT does by itself. But you're not doing anything with the data it returns.

Comment: Okay. I haven't structured my script properly. And maybe that's why it's blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two sql connections, one for each DB. Then simply get the data from one DB (perform operations, if required) and write to the second DB.

Answer (score 1):

You have two approaches for this:

1. Create two separate DB connections and manipulate data there. Passing `$conn` as connection to MySQL queries will work.
2. Use the same database using different DB prefixes. Say for example, for first DB it should be

`mb_` (Manage Books)

and

`bb_` (Borrow Books)

If I were at your place, I would have preferred second approach.

Comment: Why do you need DB prefixes? You can access tables in any database with `database.tablename`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, its more easy in my perspective to use prefixes to make only one database work instead of two different.

Comment: But the whole premise of the question is that there are two databases. You're basically saying that the answer to how to work with two databases is to NOT work with two databases.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest that you use MYSQLI or DO since MYSQL is deprecated.
These are suggestions not a fix.

Use only one connect function, you don't need two of them just use the same variable $con.

Add some error checks in there to make sure you are connecting properly

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from books where acc_number='$acc_number'") or die ("error message here");
```

For this

```
$query="INSERT INTO borrowers (title) VALUES ('$title')";
mysql_query($query);
if($query){
    header("Location:../librarysystem/books.php");
    }
```

Try

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO borrowers (title) VALUES ('$title')") or die("Could not insert...");
    if($query){
        header("Location:../librarysystem/books.php");
        }
```